# Removing rows from data frame below threshold

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe (data6):

> data6

```
   n   S_ID      EID VO
1: 1   41883100   1 A1
2: 2   41883100   2 B22
3: 3   41883100   3 C13
4: 4   41883100   4 D18
5: 5   41883100   5 T5-7
6: 6   41883098   1 HJ89
7: 7   41883098   2 I982
8: 8   41884555   1 ZX567
9: 9   41997896   1 TYU12
```

I would like to keep in data6 all the rows that their maximal EID column values is greater than 2 per S_ID (deleting values of EID per S_ID that is 1 or 2). So the result will be as followed:

> data6

```
   n   S_ID      EID VO
1: 1   41883100   1 A1
2: 2   41883100   2 B22
3: 3   41883100   3 C13
4: 4   41883100   4 D18
5: 5   41883100   5 T5-7
```

Rows 6 and 7 were deleted since for their S_ID the maximal EID was 2. Row 8 and row 9 were deleted since for each of their S_ID the maximal EID value was 1.
Rows 1 to 5 are kept since the maximal value for their S_ID is 5 (in row 5) so all their relevant rows are kept (1 to 5).

Comment: @Jaap `max(data6[data6$S_ID=4183100,"EID"]) > 2` If I inderstood properly OP's question

Comment: @Tensibai it returns `FALSE` for me

Comment: @Jaap was pseudo code for the idea, it is non working as I didn't check my text, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grouped by 'S_ID', `if` `any` of the 'EID' is greater than 2, we get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data6)[, if(any(EID > 2)) .SD , by = S_ID]
#       S_ID n EID   VO
#1: 41883100 1   1   A1
#2: 41883100 2   2  B22
#3: 41883100 3   3  C13
#4: 41883100 4   4  D18
#5: 41883100 5   5 T5-7
```

Comment: Thanks looks good! But why I get: > data6[,if( any(EID >2)) .SD , S_ID]
Error in `[.data.frame`(data6, , if (any(EID > 2)) .SD, S_ID) : 
  object 'S_ID' not found

Comment: @Avi You have a `data.frame`.  Initially I used `setDT` to convert to 'data.table'`, but then your data looked like a data.table output

Answer (score 5):

On base R:

```
data6[data6$S_ID %in% data6$S_ID[data6$EID>2],]
```

Inner to outer the idea is to

1. get the EID > 2 with `data6$EID>2`
2. get the corresponding S_ID with `data6$S_ID[<1 above>]`
3. get the logical vector corresponding to this <2> `data6$S_ID %in% <2>`
4. filter the original dataframe byt the logical vector get on <3>